# IF Statement With OR and AND

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, if-statement

Below is my current if statement. I'm trying to check if certain files exist and it appears that my first check, with the (or/and) is not picking up any of those files and thus failing down to the msgbox statment. I've added ( ) where I thought it makes sense but still doesn't pick up any file.

Currently, files 2.txt and 4.txt do exist in C:\Temp.

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

```
If (My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\1.txt") Or _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\2.txt") Or _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\3.txt")) And _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\4.txt") Then

<<do something here1>>

Else

Msgbox("No files exist.")

EndIf
```

Comment: Is the `If` condition always evaluating to `False`? Also, have you tried placing each statement individually in your watch window to single out the offending condition?

Comment: You say it's "not hitting this check." What do you mean by that? Do you mean the code isn't running at all, or that it's always failing the test where you think it should be succeeding? Assuming the latter, a suggestion to help debug this: assign the result of each call to `.FileExists` to a local `Boolean` variable (`Exists1`, `Exists2`, etc) and use those booleans in the `If` statement. This way you can more easily work out why your condition has a different value to the one you expect.

Comment: @varocarbas, if you copy the OP's check into a text editor, put it on one line, and then replace the `FileExists` checks with letters, then you get `(A Or B Or C) And D`

Comment: @varocarbas -- Current version of the OP: (1 or 2 or 3) and 4.  See the parens in the OP?

Comment: @DanPuzey Well... have to recognise that I was wrong. You are right.

Comment: @DanPuzey Correct, its failing down to the msgbox, which in fact there are files in the directory, 2.txt and 4.txt.

Comment: @DanPuzey... today I have dealt with quite a few "special people". This kind of people is not good anywhere and that's why I showed a not-too-nice attitude. I apologise if it was uncalled

Comment: @DanPuzey I don't feel anger. Just intend to avoid certain behaviours to grow. This is a community to learn and to help others; certain kind of attitudes are not good here (or anywhere else). This time I might be wrong but well... (it has been too much coincidence too).

Comment: All, this is not the comment section is not the place for chat and banter. It would be best if all off-topic content was removed.

Comment: @Muhnamana: can you use local variables as I suggested to work out which `FileExists` call doesn't have the result you expect?

Comment: @DanPuzey You were spot on with the boolean. The one file was not named correctly, which i overlooked. It had an extra space in it, which obviously threw everthing off. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: Perhaps you should take some advantage of this "situation" and maximise the information: better use OrElse and AndAlso (don't make any difference here but might make it in other contexts). Also you are using "too old code", better rely on System.IO methods. Next time, perhaps you should post a clear enough code to let people come easily and avoid misunderstandings (your code is not immediately-understandable). Some people is happy with misunderstandings but I guess that you are mainly interested in getting a quick and accurate solution.

Comment: @varocarbas: There's nothing about the posted code that's not understandable. The blowup in the comment thread here was entirely due to you misreading the question and then acting aggressively when people suggested that your solution wasn't useful. Let it go and move on.

Comment: @DanPuzey... neither say "move on"; because there is nothing here. Just a small misunderstanding, I have apologised for. But still not sure about why this misunderstanding happened precisely today and that's why I am asking. I am always keen on knowing more. And on contributing towards making from SO a better place (by removing certain behaviours; including mine, logically).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately I was missing a paren.

Thanks to @Dan Puzey for suggesting the use of `Boolean` to check if the file existed. While using this, my file truly did not exist because the file had an extra space.

I ended up still using the IF statement, adding two extra parens and now it appears to working.

@varocarbas had originally suggested this as an answer (still not quite sure why it was deleted though) but wanted to give credit where credit was due.

```
If ((My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\1.txt") Or _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\2.txt") Or _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\3.txt"))) And _
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\4.txt") Then

<<do something here1>>

Else

Msgbox("No files exist.")

EndIf
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want check are all files existed then use `AndAlso`:
    will return true if all four files exist

```
If  My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\1.txt") AndAlso
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\2.txt") AndAlso
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\3.txt") AndAlso
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\4.txt") Then

    <<do something here1>>

Else

   Msgbox("No files exist.")

EndIf
```

If you want to check if any from  files exist then use `OrElse`
    will return true if any from these file exist

```
If  My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\1.txt") OrElse
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\2.txt") OrElse
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\3.txt") OrElse
    My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists("C:\Temp\4.txt") Then

    <<do something here1>>

Else

   Msgbox("No files exist.")

EndIf
```

Comment: Using `OrElse` and `AndAlso` won't make any difference to the result of the expression - this doesn't answer the original question.